# Deploying a website and App Insights with an ARM template but putting App Insights in another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a simple ARM template:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "hostingPlanName": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "WebsiteName": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        },
        "externalResourceGroupName": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of a resource group if the deployment need to deploy to an RG that is not the current RG."
          }
        }
      },
      "variables": {
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
          "kind": "api",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Website"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
          ],
          "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(parameters('externalResourceGroupName'), 'microsoft.web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
              "use32BitWorkerProcess": "false",
              "AlwaysOn": true,
              "phpVersion": "Off"
            },
            "clientAffinityEnabled": false
          },
          "resources": [
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
          "location": "Central US",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "[parameters('webSiteName')]"
          },
          "properties": {
            "applicationId": "[parameters('webSiteName')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

You can see the following resource for App Insights:
**Microsoft.Insights/components**

The thing is, I want to deploy the website and app insights with this single template but I want to specify that the app insights resource get deployed to a different resource group to the web site.

For example

- Website resource group - **rgWebSite**
- App insights resource group -   **rgAppInsights**

You will note that my website sets its App Service Plan (ServerFarmId) to be one that is in another resource group so the same should be possible with app insights.

Comment: Pretty sure that the scope of a single template is a single resource group, and to do what you're after you need to create a second template and make a second call, as per the name of the api - `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: @russell young. That's what I thought. I know I can point to an external resource group to an existing component but not create one externally to the current Resource group from within the current template. Thanks for confirming

Comment: As far as I learned, if you want to deploy a script to different resource groups, you need to have them separate. Maybe you can use powershell, than there should be not restricted.