# Disabling ARR Affinity using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

I want to configure the app-setting "ARR Affinity" to be turned off when provisioning a new app service via our ARM template. How do I do this?

I can not find anything about this, which kind of indicates that there currently is no support for it yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for `clientAffinityEnabled` under `properties` of your `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource.

Comment: Is this set under siteConfig?

Comment: Its under properties, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601329/deploying-a-website-and-app-insights-with-an-arm-template-but-putting-app-insigh

Answer (score 8):

Below is a fully tested working ARM Template which deploy a Azure Web App with "**ARR Affinity**" set to **OFF** after deployed successfully.

Useful reference: [Disable Session affinity cookie (ARR cookie) for Azure web apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "hostingplan.name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '-hp')]"
    },
    "webapp.name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingplan.name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingplan.name')]"
      },
      "location": "[parameters('location')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "name": "[parameters('webapp.name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "properties": {
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingplan.name'))]"
      },
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingplan.name'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @juvchan, Great example , very useful. +1